# Hide some information like server name from WinSCP output

Tags: vba, ftp, winscp

I want to use WinSCP command line in my application. I want to inline all commands and not have script file.

Is it possible to hide server name?
I don't want the users know the server name.

I need to have command window visible in order to see the progress of download file.

```
Call Shell("c:\program files (x86)\winscp\winscp.com /ini=nul /command ""open ftp://user:password@servername/ "" ""get -latest /public_ftp/incoming/* c:\local\"" ""exit""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is doable, but it involves a lot of advanced code for redirecting an output of `winscp.com`, and filtering out the information you do not want to show.

---

Easier is to use [WinSCP .NET assembly from PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) instead. That gives you a full control over the output.

Just execute something like this:

`PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command "$sessionUrl = 'ftp://user:password@servername/' ; $remotePath = '/public_ftp/incoming' ; $localPath = 'c:\local' ; try { Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll' ; $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions ; $sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl) ; echo 'Opening connection'; $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session ; $session.add_FileTransferProgress( { Write-Host -NoNewline ([char]13 + '{0} ({1:P0})' -f $_.FileName, $_.FileProgress) } ); $session.Open($sessionOptions) ; echo 'Finding latest file'; $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath) ; $latest = $directoryInfo.Files | Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 ; if ($latest -eq $Null) { Write-Host 'No file found' ; exit; }; echo 'Downloading file'; $session.GetFiles([WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask([WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($remotePath, $latest.Name)), $localPath + '\*').Check(); echo ' Done';  } catch { Write-Host $_.Exception.Message; }"`

The PowerShell code is basically equivalent to [WinSCP article on Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#powershell).

It's just merged into a single command, so that you can execute it from VBA `Shell` function (after properly doubling the double quotes).

```
Call Shell ( _
  "PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command """ & _
    "$sessionUrl = 'ftp://user:password@servername/';" & _
    "$remotePath = '/public_ftp/incoming';" & _
    "$localPath = 'c:\local';" & _
    "try {" & _
    "  Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll'; " & _
    "  $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions; " & _
    "  $sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl); " & _
    "  echo 'Opening connection'; " & _
    "  $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session; " & _
    "  $session.add_FileTransferProgress( { Write-Host -NoNewline ([char]13 + '{0} ({1:P0})' -f $_.FileName, $_.FileProgress) } ); " & _
    "  $session.Open($sessionOptions); " & _
    "  echo 'Finding latest file'; " & _
    "  $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath); " & _
    "  $latest = $directoryInfo.Files | Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | " & _
    "    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1; " & _
    "  if ($latest -eq $Null) { Write-Host 'No file found' ; exit; }; " & _
    "  echo 'Downloading file'; " & _
    "  $sourcePath = [WinSCP.RemotePath]::EscapeFileMask([WinSCP.RemotePath]::Combine($remotePath, $latest.Name)); " & _
    "  $session.GetFiles($sourcePath, $localPath + '\*').Check(); " & _
    "  echo ' Done'; " & _
    "} catch { Write-Host $_.Exception.Message; }")
```

[image]